# SSRS Reports: troubles on footer island

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, navision

I have to make a Navision report (I'm using ReportBuilder for layout) where from one table I get all the data relative to many bills, the records are tagged either as Header, Detail or Footer, print in this report a summary of all these bills I have, and after all the summaries are done, I have to print three more pages where I will show some data relative to these bills.

So we can split this in two sections: bills section (first N pages, depending on the number of bills) and informations section (last 3 pages).

My problem is, I have to show at the end of each page in the bills section a subtotal regarding the bills in the current page. This is going to print, so layout is really important.

- How do i pin the footer to the bottom of the page?
- In the informations section I have to show a different footer

For point number two, I worked out something: I put in 3 rects with page break before, inside each of these there is an information page, and since it's fixed length (while bills section is not) i can put my stuff where it pleases me most and be done with layout. But if I do this, showing the footer for the bills section will be a problem.

I can't use a page footer because otherwise in the informations section i would see the footer. I could hide the contens, but it would still use my precious space. And by the way, I can't get that damn footer to stay at the bottom of the page if the page isn't full :)

I can't use table footer because I will either
- Get a footer at the end of each bill
- Get a footer only after all the bills

Since there is a fixed number of pages in informations section, it's easy for me to understand if i'm in bills section or informations section by doing (TotalPages - PageNumber). But how can I put this to use?

Is there a way to make a field/rect/something appear in EVERY page, at the bottom of the page? If it can be done, hiding it in informations is easy.

Is there any solution/workaround/anything that comes to mind?

PS: I haven't tought about it, but is there some NAV-side code that could help me?

Comment: Can't you just use a table footer and set it to repeat on every page?

Comment: I don't know... In the last three pages the footer should not be shown, can I hide it only on these pages? And still, I don't know how to send the footer at the bottom of the printable page instead of at the end of the page content

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have a solution:

To send the footer on the bottom of the page, i just realized i was seeing it wrong because I was looking at the Preview instead of Print Layout.

To hide/show a different footer for the last three pages, I will overlap all the textboxes I may need and show them selectively depending on page number.

The footer will always occupy the same amount of space, but at least I can show useful info only.

If someone knows a way to change footer height during runtime it would be super useful.